# Possible holonomy groups of flat manifolds?

Tags: topological-groups, holonomy

I have been recently reading about "holonomy" groups (not to be confused with "homology"). It seems a rather esoteric subject that is not found in many introductions to topology.

Anyway, for a flat manifold, (e.g. a flat torus), is the holonomy group always either the simple group or a discrete group? (By flat I mean the Riemann tensor is zero everywhere not just the Ricci tensor).

My intuition says that in order to get a continuous holonomy group like $SO(n)$ your manifold would have to have some curvature. Would this be a correct assumption?

P.S. I would like to learn more about advanced topology, are there any good books to start?

Comment: This is not "topology", but instead "differential geometry". Your intuition about curvature is right because of the Ambrose-Singer theorem. The holonomy group of a orientable Riemannian manifold is always a subgroup of ${\rm SO}(n)$ and, when this holonomy group is a Lie group, the holonomy algebra is generated by curvature endomorphisms. So, no curvature means "no holonomy".

Comment: Thanks, well that explains why I couldn't find it in the topology books!

Comment: @IvoTerek Is that strictly true? Since the holonomy of a cone can be a discrete group? If you transport a vector around the point it rotates. Well, I suppose you could say a cone has a non-trivial point of curvature. What about a cube where you identify opposite sides but with a 90 degree twist?